# Rearrange items in lists to converge their averages

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, average

This isn't really a programming question, actually it's more of an algorithmic question. One of my functionality requirements ask of me to limit the difference of the averages to within a certain range.

Take for example:

```
a: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}    // avg: 3
b: {2, 3, 3, 4, 6}    // avg: 3.4
c: {4, 4, 5, 7, 6}    // avg: 5.2
```

If the maximum difference of the averages were 2, then:

- Difference between averages of `a` and `b` would be valid
- Difference between averages of `b` and `c` would be valid
- Difference between averages of `a` and `c` would **not** be valid

I then have to rearrange (e.g. swap *1* from `a`  with *7* from `b` so that the averages become closer to each other, and their differences is within the maximum specified.

My question then is: how can I most efficiently (with the least amount of moves) rearrange the items such that the averages converge to within the specified maximum average difference?

I'm not actually looking for a clear-cut answer, but if anybody has an inkling of what I should be looking for, I'd be more than happy to hear from you. If this doesn't belong to StackOverflow, my apologies, perhaps you could direct me elsewhere?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: *"This isn't really a programming question"* - Then it isn't really on-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because *it isn't a programming question*

Comment: Have you a reference average value or only a maximum difference value?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Maybe the algorithm tag should be removed from stackoverflow?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to swap numbers located in different positions in two different arrays? This restriction would further reduce the search space.

Answer (score 0):

First sum all the numbers, then divide the sum by the number of arrays. In this example we have 59 / 3

The result of the integer division will be used to determine the size of each napsack corrected so as to have the sum of the sizes of the knapsacks match the sum of all numbers. In this example, 
Knapsack sizes are 19, 20 and  20.

Next, find all the solutions to the multiple knapsack problem.

Last, the solution that can be reached with the least number of moves from the initial state is the optimum.

Comment: This seems like a robust and easy-to-implement solution but unfortunately I think it renders my maximum average difference useless? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Mapping your problem to multiple knapsack means that you need to solve a NP complete problem. That's OK for small data sets but for large ones, you are forced to use heuristics and fall for a suboptimal solution. The object of what I presented is to show that your  maps to a standard known problem with a known complexity.

Comment: The other reason, was to show that you have to solve two problems in one. Multiple knapsack + minimum number of swaps. Thinking about it, since the number of items has to be the same in each knapsack (as swapping leaves the cardinality of each set as is), the search space is reduced considerably.

Comment: That would mean that you would have 59 chose 19 for the first knapsack,  then 40 chose 20 for the second. That's the number of combinations.

Comment: Another point I would like to make is that if you swap numbers away towards an lesser difference in average at each swap, following a greedy approach, you might end up stuck in a local optima.

Comment: I would also like to point you towards the constraint programming algorithm that might give you another perspective.